# How can I modify the thickness of an inset after it was done?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

Is there a way that I can alter the thickness of an inset after it was done?

Comment: No, there is not. Use modifiers whenever possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not strictly possible, however, it is practically possible using the following easy steps.

1. Select the inset loop using <kbd>alt</kbd> + *right click*
2. Press <kbd>G</kbd> twice to enter *edge slide mode*
3. Move your mouse to resize as desired.

**Note:** as with any other action, you can also press<kbd>space</kbd> and type *edge slide* if you don't remember the shortcut.

Comment: It may be easier to just press "G" key twice and it'll go to edge slide.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know about that shortcut and will add it to my answer.